# Can we add more than one viewControllers to UIPageViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, uipageviewcontroller

I am looking for UIPageViewController and found this:
http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/

It's suspicious. Why does it insert an array of just 1 viewController initially.

So I made a program trying to insert 2-10. The program works if I just insert 1 viewController initially. However, if I try to insert 2-10, it doesn't work.

```
   [self.containerView addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;

    NSMutableArray * arrayOfControllers=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i<1 ; i++) { //if I set this into for (int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) { instead it wouldn't work
        BlankImageViewController *contentViewController = [[BlankImageViewController alloc] init];
        contentViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
        [arrayOfControllers addObject:contentViewController];
        //contentViewController.labelContents = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray *viewControllers = @[arrayOfControllers.lastObject];
    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfControllers]; //If this line is commented it works
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:nil];
```

If viewControllers have only one element it works. self.pageViewController.viewControllers will be filled with that 1 element.

if viewControllers have more than one element, then things do not work anymore. self.pageViewController.viewControllers will have empty array.

I wonder why. I am new to UIPageViewController. If you can only fill one UIViewController why ask for an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just one page at a time showing, there is one view controller. If you have two pages at a time showing, there are two view controllers.

By the way, my book teaches you to get started with Page View Controller:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_page_view_controller

But I haven't updated it yet for iOS 6 and the new scroll transition style.

Comment: Perfect. So it can only contain either 1 or 2 pages at a time.

Comment: I thought the function is to add the whole ViewControllers to be displayed. I wonder if the documentation can be made even more vague.

Comment: The docs are clear. You are a data source, so you supply a requested view controller on demand. Similar to table views and other things that have data sources. Efficient. Otherwise for a thousand-page book you'd need a thousand view controllers all at once, which is nutso.

Comment: Ahh..... I see. So I an not supposed to have an array of viewController anywhere. I should have an array of object and create a new viewController when needed. That's the way it's intended to be done right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. Upvoted checked as answer :D The documentation wasn't that clear for me. You are. You should have written the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned, I've written an entire book on iOS programming. With downloadable examples.

Comment: I also have exactly same question but doesn't got your point here, can it be solved or not. can you guys help me.